# COM interface: Using STA instead of MTA

Tags: multithreading, com, activex

I am working with a COM interface that, according to ThreadingModel = "Free" in it's CLSID entry in the registry, supports multithreaded apartments. Multithreading seems to be implemented at a very basic level, however, very often method calls return a "Class is busy" status code.

Is there any risk of switching to STAs in CoInitializeEx and using interface marshaling to have the COM system serialize the requests and to avoid this behaviour (which I never experienced when only making calls from the main thread)?

Thanks!

Comment: What's "class is busy" exactly? If the registry is correct (and the object is really "free"), you can initialize COM threads the way you want.

Comment: @SimonMourier "class is busy" is a status code defined by the manufacturer of the COM class, returned by method calls. It is _not_ a general COM thing.

Comment: @SimonMourier "you can initialize COM threads the way you want" refers to switching to STAs and interface marshaling?

Comment: The business state does not look dependent on COM apartment model choice. It rather looks that the object is just doing its own thing and prefers to abort with this returned code.

Comment: @RomanR. I agree, this is what it seems like. Do you agree that switching to STA and leaving serialization to the COM system should work because of that?

Comment: No, I don't think so. According to you, status code is manufacturer defined. It's their internal status, not COM related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an STA thread to host the COM object will not make any difference.  COM pays attention to the ThreadingModel value in the registry.  Since it is "Free", it will not see any need to marshal the interface pointer and will *still* makes the call from the worker thread.

You would have to monkey with the registry key and change it to "Both".

This is not a great solution, it will break at a drop of a hat.  It is just far better to take care of this yourself.  Use Control.Begin/Invoke() or Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke(), depending on which class library you use to implement the *required* message loop.  Note that you now also have a choice, the COM marshaling is equivalent to Invoke() but you can (possibly) optimize by using BeginInvoke().

And last but not least, duplicating the locking that exists in the COM server that produces the "busy" error code is a possible solution.  Non-zero odds that you'll solve this by acquiring your own lock before you make each call, thus serializing the calls yourself.  Your worker thread will now block instead of having to deal with the error code.  Contacting the author of the component would be wise, he can easily tell you which *specific* methods you should serialize.

Comment: I had the chance to test the STA thread by now and the behaviour was exactly as described. I am protecting the calls with critical sections now. Thanks!